# Why is this LINQ Where clause not returning results?

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

We have an entity with DateTime property `DateDestroyed`. A query needs to return results where this value is between nullable DateTimes `startDate` and `endDate`.

The where clauses I have are:

```
.Where(x => startDate.HasValue ? startDate <= x.DateDestroyed : true)
.Where(x => endDate.HasValue ? x.DateDestroyed <= endDate : true);
```

The query always return no results. I'm pretty sure I haven't written this query properly but don't know how it should be written or why it's not working?

Comment: DO you get results by using only one of the wheres?

Comment: Are you changing the value of `startDate` or `endDate` after the query is composed?

Comment: do any of these answers help you? It appears there was a drive-by downvoter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create/use an extension method for `WhereIf`:

Given a boolean condition, append a `Where` clause.

```
 var foo = db.Customers.WhereIf(startDate.HasValue, 
                                   x => startDate <= x.DateDestroyed)
                       .WhereIf(endDate.HasValue,  
                                   x => x.DateDestroyed <= endDate );
```

More details at [WhereIf at ExtensionMethod.net](http://www.extensionmethod.net/Details.aspx?ID=242). You can find the code there for `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: @randomDownvoter: care to explain your downvote and how this answer doesn't help solve the problem?

Comment: I got the same thing p.campbell, I'm pretty sure my answer also would have worked. :(

Answer (score 1):

My code requires IQueryable so I adapted the work by [@p.campbell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23199/p-campbell) at [ExtensionMethod.net](http://www.extensionmethod.net/Details.aspx?ID=242) as follows:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereIf<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, bool condition, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    return condition ? source.Where(predicate).AsQueryable() : source;
}

public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereIf<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, bool condition, Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate)
{
    return condition ? source.Where(predicate).AsQueryable() : source;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have a variable called "query" that you've stored the beginning part of your linq statement.  Try this to dynamically construct the where clause:

```
if (startDate.HasValue) {
    query = query.Where(x => x.DateDestroyed >= startDate);
}
if (endDate.HasValue) {
    query = query.Where(x => x.DateDestroyed <= endDate);
}
```

LINQ works on deferred execution so the WHERE clause will correctly resolve when the code executes.

Answer (score -1):

Are you always re-assigning your query with the `Where()` filter applied?

This pattern should work as expected:

```
var query = getResults();
query = query.Where(x => startDate.HasValue ? startDate <= x.DateDestroyed : true)
query = query.Where(x => endDate.HasValue ? x.DateDestroyed <= endDate : true);
```

Comment: I use this pattern all the time, it should work.. ? Did you downvote? I don't think my suggestion was worth the downvote.